# Testing after_transition with Rspec & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, state-machine

I have two models: LessonBooking and CustomerRequests

Once a LessonBooking was paid, associated CustomerRequests get marked as booked. Note: LessonBooking are not directly associated via an id but customers enter their email when they pay and this email is used to check for existing customer requests which are marked as "booked" if found. Here is the relevant code in lesson_booking.rb:

```
event :payment_received do
  transition :form_started => :paid
end
after_transition :form_started => :paid do |booking|
  email = booking.teaching_relationship.student.account.email
  customer_request = CustomerRequest.find_by_email(email)
  unless customer_request.nil?
    customer_request.book
  end
end
```

The CustomerRequest model itself also has a state machine that has an event "book" as
shown here:

```
event :book do
  transition [:new, :opened, :awaiting_response] => :booked
end
```

Now I am incapable of getting a spec passed that tests the transition of LessonBooking from "form_started" to "paid" and the following transition of CustomerRequest from "new" to "booked".

Here is the spec I wrote:

```
context 'when there is an associated customer request' do
  before :each do
    @student = create(:student)
    relationship = create(:teaching_relationship, student: @student)
    @new_booking = create(:lesson_booking, teaching_relationship: relationship)
    @customer_request = create(:customer_request, student: @student, email: @student.account.email )
  end

  it "it changes the state of the customer request" do
    @new_booking.payment_received
    expect(@customer_request.state).to eq 'booked'
  end
end
```

end

My test always fails with the following note:

```
expected: "booked"
got: "new"
```

I am knew to testing in general and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: abstract it to a method, check if it's received, then test the method in isolation

Comment: ok, so you mean I should write a method for the code within the after_transition :form_started to :paid, right? if so, how would I check/test if it's received?

Comment: Something like: `after_transition :form_started => :paid, do: :method_name`